# Key by Kafka partition / Kinesis shard

Tags: apache-flink

I want to build a simple Flink application that batches Kinesis/Kafka records belonging to the same shard/partition and saves them to S3.

The problem is that I don't understand how to key my source on shard id, and do it in a way that doesn't induce unnecessary shuffling.

Is this possible with Flink?

Comment: Why do you need to key them by shard/partition? Do you need to use keyed state (or timers)? I have an alternative in mind, but I don't know how relevant it is.

Comment: The only thing that I have in mind is to simply extract `shardId` or `key` using `KinesisDeserializationSchema` or `KafkaDeserializationSchema` and pass that downstream and then use that in `keyBy()`, but that doesn't guarantee that there will be no shuffling.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes, I need timers for making 5 minute batches.

Comment: @DominikWosiński Yeah I thought about this, but as you said there will be this unnecessary shuffling.

Comment: What are you going to do with the 5 minute batches? Could you simply use the FileSink with a 5-minute rolling policy, or do you intend to do some windowed aggregations?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes, I want to transform these batches.